# SQL Server 2014 Express Replication

Tags: database-replication, publisher, sql-server-2014-express

I'm new to Sql Server and would like to know whether can setup SQL Server 2014 Express as a Publisher Server for Replication? I cannot find the Local Publication node in Replication folder tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express supports witness only. See the link below for features supported by the different editions of SQL Server 2014.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx